# Can't disable auto-scrolling

Tags: auctex, emacsclient

When I scroll up or down, Emacs automatically recenters the current position of point. I tried to disable this behavior by adding the following code to my configuration:

```el
(setq scroll-margin 1
      scroll-conservatively 10000
      scroll-up-aggressively 0.01
      scroll-down-aggressively 0.01
      auto-hscroll-mode nil
      scroll-step 1)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I really tried all variables I can find.

NB: I am using AUCTeX and `emacsclient`.

Comment: **Read** the doc strings for scroll-step and scroll-conservatively and choose one or the other.  I suggest you try Emacs -Q and set scroll-conservatively to 101 and see if you like it -- **without** any other settings.  Then perhaps add scroll-margin if you want scrolling before reaching the window edges.  My understanding is 101 and a billion trillion have the same effect.

Comment: In fact, I tested without emacsclient, it works (no auto scrolling), but when i start emacs with emacs --daemon and then use emacsclient, even I've checked with C-h C-v that the scroll-conservatively is set to 101 (or sth big), it does auto scroll to center always.

Answer (score 3):

This variable preserves both the point and the screen position when scrolling:

```
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always)
```